# How to do progressive substraction with lookup in Excel?

Tags: excel, excel-formula

Take a look at following picture

[image: excel-problem]

What I wanted to do is to calculate remaining value (progressive substraction) with **lookup** functionality (like vlookup, or something like that).

So in cell E2 I want the excel **to search within column A** look for text of **"for A"** and return the associated amount (in column B), after that add/sum all of the amount associated with "for A", **then** substract **value in cell D2** with **total sum of "for A's" amount**.

Same thing for column E3, E4, and E5, just replace the lookup text with "for B", "for C", and "for D".

How to do that?

Thanks.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If I understand, you just want to do a subtraction, with `SumIf()`:

In E2, you can use `=E2-SUMIF($A$2:$A$21,D2,$B$2:$B$21)`

That will subtract what's in E2, from the Sum of values in Column B, where Column A is `for A`. If you drag down, it'll then use `for B`, `for C`, and `for D` as the "lookup".

Answer (score 1):

You can use plenty of solutions for that. I'd first recommend using `SUMPRODUCT` where you can categorize the `sum` of each amount by the `purpose`. You can subtract the result of that value from your calculation in the same *new* formula.

Here's a snapshot of a sample worksheet:

[Using SUMPRODUCT](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Xop5l.png)

Other than than, you can use Pivot Tables, `sumif` function and [Consolidate](https://support.office.com/en-us/article/Consolidate-data-in-multiple-worksheets-007ce8f4-2fae-4fea-9ee5-a0b2c9e36d9b?NS=EXCEL&Version=16&SysLcid=1033&UiLcid=1033&AppVer=ZXL160&HelpId=21004&ui=en-US&rs=en-US&ad=US) to summarize and include the result in different calculations.